# jQuery Waypoints cached pages

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using jQuery Waypoints to make a menu to appear under the logo once I scroll down the page. Everything is working fine except when I visit a new page and then I come back to the mid-scrolled one.

Let's say I visit a page and I scroll down to half of the document. Then I go to a new page clicking on a link. If I go back the firast page I get everything messed.

Is there any way to cache the position of the page and say it to Waypoints?
Maybe not the perfect English, sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save scroll position in cookies and check it